# TYPO3 create query

Tags: php, mysql, typo3, extbase

I am trying to create a simple query using TYPO3 . I'm trying to retrieve all results from a table  where the name starts with a numerical value , then sort them. Unfortunately creating a $statement variable doesn't work. How can I do this using the TYPO3 type of queries ( `$query->matching`,`$query->like`). Thank you for your answer.

UPDATE:

TYPO3 Version : 8.7.3
What I tried :

```
public function sortReferencesNumerically(){
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $statement = 'select * from tx_referencemanager_domain_model_reference WHERE name REGEXP '^[0-9]' ORDER BY CAST(name as SIGNED INTEGER) ASC';
    $query->statement($statement);
    return $query->execute();
}
```

NewUpdate : Unfortunately i can't use the $statement method , even tough it works. Is there anyway to do this without the query->statement method ? 
I tried this , but it only shows the first data in the table that starts with a numerical character, even tough I have like 20-30.

```
 array_push($queryConstraints, $query->logicalOr([
                    $query->like('name', '0%'),
                    $query->like('name', '1%'),
                    $query->like('name', '2%'),
                    $query->like('name', '3%'),
                    $query->like('name', '4%'),
                    $query->like('name', '5%'),
                    $query->like('name', '6%'),
                    $query->like('name', '7%'),
                    $query->like('name', '8%'),
                    $query->like('name', '9%'),
                ]));
```

Comment: Can you be more specific and post the exact code you have tried? Also more details about your setup (TYPO3 version, extension, etc.)

Comment: Your string is broken. If you encapsulate a string in single quotes, dont use single quotes to delimit the regex.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your string is broken. If you encapsulate a string in single quotes, dont use single quotes to delimit the regex.

This should work:

```
public function sortReferencesNumerically(){
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $statement = 'select * from tx_referencemanager_domain_model_reference WHERE name REGEXP \'^[0-9]\' ORDER BY CAST(name as SIGNED INTEGER) ASC';
    $query->statement($statement);
    return $query->execute();
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this , without the $statement method?

Comment: None that I know of. Regular Expressions are not implemented in Extbase, as far as i know. Maybe you should separate whatever that value represents into a separate integer column.